# Why Redis use "sizemask" to replace size?

Tags: data-structures, redis

```c++
typedef struct dictht {
    dictEntry **table;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long sizemask;
    unsigned long used;
} dictht;
```

As shown in the above code,where sizemask = size - 1 in the data struct of redis's hashtable(dictht),
why would redis use sizemask to calculate the postion of hashtable's element？
I don't think bit operation is more effective than % operation.
(Sorry my English is poor, but I realy want to know the design ideas of sizemask.)

Comment: bit operation has much better performance than % operation

Comment: https://mziccard.me/2015/05/08/modulo-and-division-vs-bitwise-operations/